# MASM winsock error?

Tags: assembly, winsock, masm

I'm following along with a winsock tutorial in MASM's syntax called: Iczelion's Guide to Winsock Programming

I'm stuck, I receive an error but I don't know how to fix it.
The thing is that everytime I try to connect to a server with my socket, I receive a WSANOTSOCK error (a socket opperation is preformed on something that is not a socket)

But there was no error when calling WSAStartup() or Socket(). So how can this error be here now?

Here's the code I'm currently using (I said I followed Iczelion's Guide to Winsock Programming, but I've modefied it to suit my needs, I'm trying to create an irc bot)

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap: none


include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\user32.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
include \masm32\include\shell32.inc
include \masm32\include\wsock32.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\shell32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 
includelib \masm32\lib\wsock32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib




.data

txt db "An error occured while calling WSAStartup",0
txt1 db "An error occured while creating a socket",0
txt2 db "An error occured while connecting",0
capt db "SCHiM",0
wsadata WSADATA <>
hostname db "irc.corruptcode.org",0
Port dd 6667 
NICK db "NICK SCHiMBot",0
USER db "USER SCHIMR 8 * :SCHMRR",0
CHANNEL db "/join #botts",0
sin sockaddr_in <?> 

.data?
sock dd ? 
;ErrorCode dd ?   
ErrorCode  dd ?

.code
start:
invoke WSAStartup, 101h,addr wsadata

.if eax!=NULL   ;An error occured if eax != null, because there's no return value for this api, if there's return, there's an error

mov ErrorCode, eax

push MB_OK
push offset capt
push offset txt
push 0
call MessageBoxA


.else

invoke socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0     ; Create a stream socket for internet use
invoke WSAGetLastError


.if eax!=INVALID_SOCKET
    mov sock,eax
.else
    invoke WSAGetLastError

push MB_OK
push offset capt
push offset txt1
push 0
call MessageBoxA
 .endif

; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤
;Now we have a socket ready for use, we still have to be able to connect to somewere though...
; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤



mov sin.sin_family, AF_INET
invoke htons, Port                    ; convert port number into network byte order first
mov sin.sin_port,ax                  ; note that this member is a word-size param.
invoke gethostbyname, addr hostname
mov eax,[eax+12]                ; move the value of h_list member into eax
mov eax,[eax]                      ; copy the pointer to the actual IP address into eax
mov eax,[eax]          
mov sin.sin_addr,eax  ; copy IP address into eax


; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤
;Now That's done we can connect to a site! (an irc channel in this case)
; ¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤


invoke connect,socket,addr sin,sizeof sin



.if eax==SOCKET_ERROR           

             invoke WSAGetLastError                                          



mov ErrorCode, eax

push MB_OK
push offset capt
push offset txt2
push 0
call MessageBoxA

invoke ExitProcess, NULL



    .endif

invoke send, socket,addr USER, 100, 0
.if eax==SOCKET_ERROR
push MB_OK
push offset capt
push offset txt2
push 0
call MessageBoxA
invoke ExitProcess, NULL
.else 

invoke send, socket,addr NICK, 100, 0
invoke send, socket,addr CHANNEL, 100, 0

.endif








.endif




        invoke ExitProcess, NULL
end start
```

Thanks in advance

-Rick

Comment: Don't delete your questions when you've received an answer. Leave the question intact so the next person with a similar problem can benefit from it.

Comment: I had already spotted my mistake before I saw the posted solution, which was correct however. I will remember to leave my questions intact in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughout this part:

```
invoke send, socket,addr USER, 100, 0
.if eax==SOCKET_ERROR
push MB_OK
push offset capt
push offset txt2
push 0
call MessageBoxA
invoke ExitProcess, NULL
.else 

invoke send, socket,addr NICK, 100, 0
invoke send, socket,addr CHANNEL, 100, 0
```

where you have "socket", you intended to have "sock" -- as-is, I believe it's using the address (or maybe the first dword of) the `socket` function instead of the socket value you saved in `sock`.

If you don't mind my saying so, I think the code is kind of a mess. Cleaning it up a bit, I got this:

```
.code
show_error proc caption:ptr byte, err_txt:ptr byte
    invoke WSAGetLastError
    mov ErrorCode, eax
    invoke MessageBoxA, MB_OK, caption, err_txt, 0
    ret
show_error endp

main proc
    invoke WSAStartup, 101h,addr wsadata

    .if eax==0   ; An error occured if eax != 0, because there's no return value for this api, if there's return, there's an error
        invoke socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0     ; Create a stream socket for internet use
        .if eax!=INVALID_SOCKET
            mov sock,eax

            ;¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤
            ;Now we have a socket ready for use, we still have to be able to connect to somewere though...
            ;¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

            mov sin.sin_family, AF_INET
            invoke htons, Port  ; convert port number into network byte order first
            mov sin.sin_port,ax ; note that this member is a word-size param.
            invoke gethostbyname, addr hostname

            mov eax,[eax+12]    ; move the value of h_list member into eax
            mov eax,[eax]       ; copy the pointer to the actual IP address into eax
            mov eax,[eax]       ; copy IP address into eax
            mov sin.sin_addr,eax

            ;¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤
            ;Now That's done we can connect to a site! (an irc channel in this case)
            ;¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤¤

            invoke connect, sock, addr sin, sizeof sin
            .if eax!=SOCKET_ERROR
                invoke send, sock, addr USER, 100, 0
                .if eax!=SOCKET_ERROR
                    invoke send, sock, addr NICK, 100, 0
                    invoke send, sock, addr CHANNEL, 100, 0
                .else
                    invoke show_error, offset capt, offset txt2
                .endif
            .else
                invoke show_error, offset capt, offset txt2
            .endif
        .else
            invoke show_error, offset capt, offset txt1
        .endif
    .else
        invoke show_error, offset capt, offset txt
    .endif
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main endp
end main
```